# Identifying circular dependency when saving entites in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table called `Record`, and each `Record` has a collection of image files called `RecordImage`. The `RecordImage` table has an `IsMainImage` flag to indicate which of the `Record`'s images is the main image. There can only be one `IsMainImage` for each `Record`.

```
public class Record
{
    public Guid RecordId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RecordImage> RecordImage { get; set; }
}

public class RecordImage
{
    public Guid RecordImageId { get; set; }
    public Guid RecordId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainImage { get; set; }

    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using an ajax file uploader to update `RecordImages`, users hit a checkbox to tick the main image and the associated `RecordImage` is updated on the server. When I do this I have to check for an existing `IsMainImage` and set it to false in favor of the new one:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid key, string values)
{
RecordImage image = await _context.RecordImage.FindAsync(key);

if (image == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, image);

if (TryValidateModel(image))
{
    if (image.IsMainImage)
    {
        // Check if a different Image is already flagged as the Record's MainImage.
        RecordImage oldMainImage = await _context.RecordImage
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.RecordId == image.RecordId && a.IsMainImage && a.RecordImageId != image.RecordImageId);

        // Clear old MainImage.
        if (oldMainImage != null)
        {
            oldMainImage.IsMainImage = false;
        }
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(); 
}

return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

However, this fails with the exception:

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in
>   the data to be saved

I was able to remedy this by detaching the Image being updated and saving changes to the old MainImage and then reattaching the Image:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid key, string values)
{
RecordImage image = await _context.RecordImage.FindAsync(key);

if (image == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, image);

if (TryValidateModel(image))
{
    // Use a Transaction as we need to call SaveChanges() more than once in this operation.
    using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
    {
        // Image being updated needs to be detached before modifying and saving other entities.
        _context.Entry(image).State = EntityState.Detached;

        if (image.IsMainImage)
        {
            // Check if a different Image is already flagged as the Record's MainImage.
            RecordImage oldMainImage = await _context.RecordImage
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.RecordId == image.Record && a.IsMainImage && a.RecordImageId != image.RecordImageId);

            // Clear old MainImage.
            if (oldMainImage != null)
            {
                oldMainImage.IsMainImage = false;
            }
        }

        // Save changes to other Images before reattaching and saving changes to the Image
        // being updated.
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        _context.Entry(image).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        transaction.Commit();

        return Ok(); 
    }
}

return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

This works and gets me what I need, but I'm not entirely comfortable because I don't understand why. Previously, it seems all I was doing was updating multiple `RecordImage`s in the context, setting one's `IsMainImage` to `true` and another's `IsMainImage` to `false`. I'm not trying to update any parents or children as I'm not even `Including()` any in the context. What could be the source of this circular dependency?

Comment: Shouldn't Record.RecordImage be declared as "virtual" to enable lazy loading?

Comment: I would need to be, however I am not using Lazy Loading.